# windows 7 зеленая рамка вокруг окна приложения

Tags: windows, windows-7

Что значит, когда вокруг окна запущенного приложения зелёная рамка (примерно 3-4 пикс толщиной)? Скриншот сделать не могу, на нём эта рамка не видна. Созданные этой программой файлы не видны в папке (включен показ скрытых файлов, все равно не видно).

Файлы реально существуют, их видно через диалоговое окно "открыть файл" этой программы с рамкой. Если в этом диалоговом окне через контекстное меню попробовать открыть файл в другой программе (например Acrobat Reader), файл открывается, но Acrobat открывается тоже с зеленой рамкой.

Что происходит и как добыть этот невидимый файл? Пересохранить, архивировать, переместить в другую папку не помогает - все файлы остаются невидимыми.

Comment: https://support.kaspersky.ru/4964 оно?   или http://www.comss.ru/page.php?id=2041 оно ?

Comment: касперыча нет, но да, это Comodo, спасибо. а как созданный файл выковырять, если не отключать защиту чтоб пересоздать?

Comment: нашел. вторая, добавленная вами ссылка, помогла.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, вы как-то открыли эту программу в так называемом `Sand Box` - песочнице.

Это когда программа изолирована от других процессов и файлов.